# CMake IMPORTED UNKNOWN GLOBAL target

Tags: c++, cmake

I have hard times understanding CMake's imported libraries. Here is my test structure:

```
├── binary
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cc
├── library
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── lib.cc
│   └── lib.hh
```

The library's CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)

project(Library)

add_library(library lib.cc)
target_include_directories(library PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

And the binary's looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)

project(binary)

add_executable(binary main.cc)

find_library(il_default library PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../library/build/")

add_library(Imported::Library UNKNOWN IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET Imported::Library PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${il_default})
set_property(TARGET Imported::Library PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../library")

target_link_libraries(binary Imported::Library)
```

Build commands:

```
cmake -Blibrary/build -Hlibrary && cmake --build library/build
cmake -Bbinary/build -Hbinary && cmake --build binary/build
```

This yields the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "Imported::Library" of type UNKNOWN_LIBRARY may not be linked into
  another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to
  executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.
```

Removing the **GLOBAL** parameter from the **add_library** command, or replacing **UNKNOWN** with **STATIC** solves the problem.

My question is "Why?". Why can I use an unknown imported library within the current directory but can't make it global?

CMake version is 3.6.0

Comment: Well you have to know how to link the library. static or dynamic. If you set it to `UNKOWN` cmake cannot know how to link. Thats why cmake tells you `One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries` or you have to set the property `ENABLE_EXPORTS` (not sure what it does though)

Comment: @Hayt CMake actually knows how to link it if I remove the ````GLOBAL```` flag, even if library type is still ````UNKNOWN````

Comment: Thats strange. `GLOBAL` should only change the scope which does not change anything here.

Comment: what version of cmake are you using and can you try a newer one? I remember vaguely cmake 2 having issues with some imported libraries stuff.

Comment: @Hayt This is exactly why I'm asking. My version is 3.6.0

Comment: Either way this is a bug or some very internal thing here. You would probably get more help by using the cmake mailing list. If you get an answer there you can also feel free to share it here by answering your own question.

Comment: That bug was fixed in CMake 3.10.
See [this issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17245) in CMake's bug-tracker.